# Javascript Array observe

Tags: javascript, riot.js

observe(arr,callback) in combination with riot.js

But when I try to observe my array I get *Array.observe is not a function*.

```
Array.observe(this.nodes, function (changes) 
{
    //do some stuff
    tag.update();
});
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.observe is not a function(…)(anonymous function)
@components/breadcrumb-navigation.tag.js:3(anonymous function) 
@ riot+compiler.js:1604(anonymous function) 
@ riot+compiler.js:1719each 
@ riot+compiler.js:1921toggle 
@ riot+compiler.js:1719(anonymous function) 
@ riot+compiler.js:1610mountTo 
@ riot+compiler.js:2417pushTags 
@ riot+compiler.js:2557each 
@ riot+compiler.js:1921pushTags 
@ riot+compiler.js:2561riot.mount 
@ riot+compiler.js:2612(anonymous function) 
@ riot+compiler.js:3497done 
@ riot+compiler.js:3414compileTag 
@ riot+compiler.js:3421GET.req.onreadystatechange 
@ riot+compiler.js:3381
```

Comment: I used this function weeks ago and it works fine.  So today i was a bit confused of this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Array.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe) method is obsolete and has been removed.
The use of a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) instead is suggested.